# Сохранить видео из компонента

Tags: react-native

На экране есть видео, надо сохранить полностью компонент этого блока с видео, где оно находиться. Для картинок получилось сделать с помощью react-native-view-shot, а для видео так не получается. Какие есть решения для этого, может быть какой-то пакет, может быть какие-то костыли? Видео выводиться через react-native-video